# Android spongy castle archive for required library

Tags: android

I'm trying to add spongy castle to my android project, but I always get the following error:
Archive for required library 'lib/scprov-jdk15-1.46.99.3-UNOFFICIAL-ROBERTO-RELEASE.jar' in project 'xxx' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file.

I've read [How to include the Spongy Castle JAR in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6898801/how-to-include-the-spongy-castle-jar-in-android) and tried to find the difference between https://github.com/rtyley/spongycastle-eclipse and my project, but I don't find anything.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if it is too late, but to add BountyCastle to your project, you simply add this to the class that your going to be doing encryption in:

```
static {
     Security.addProvider(new org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
}
```

Here is an example:

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.Security;


public class SHA1PRNG {
 //here i swapped out the bountycastle provider and used the spongycatle
   static {
      Security.addProvider(new org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    SecureRandom rng = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
    rng.setSeed(711);

    int numberToGenerate = 999;
    byte randNumbers[] = new byte[numberToGenerate];

    rng.nextBytes(randNumbers);
    for(int j=0; j<numberToGenerate; j++) {
        System.out.print(randNumbers[j] + " ");
    }

}
}
```

From: 
          www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Security/SecureRandomSHA1PRNG.htm